# sendplot package error in: image() cannot found object 'x'

Tags: r, function, object

Hello i have a function that create an interactive plot with the sendplot package and i get a weird error, I search a lot on the web but i found nothing!!

I use R 2.15.1

The problem is that when I call my function I get the error:

> Error in image(x = xx, y = yy, z = zz, col = heat.colors(30), axes = FALSE)  : 
>     Cannot found object 'xx'

But if i execute my code line by line in the console it works (because xx,yy,zz,data.mat are in my workspace)
I don't understand why when I call my function the object are not in my workspace...

Here is my code:

```
   Heatmap<-function(data.mat,main.str="heatmap"){

         xx <- 0:dim(data.mat)[1] 
         yy <- 0:dim(data.mat)[2] 
         zz <- log(data.mat+1)
         plot.call = "image( x=xx,y=yy, z=zz,col = heat.colors(30),axes = FALSE);
         axis(1,0.5:(dim(data.mat)[1]-0.5),
         labels=rownames(data.mat),
         las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0,cex.axis =1);
         axis(4,0.5:(dim(data.mat)[2]-0.5),
         labels=colnames(data.mat),
         las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0,cex.axis =.8)"
         mai.mat = matrix(c(1.5,.5,.5,1.5), ncol=4)
         mai.prc = FALSE
         xy.labels=list(nb_of_sequences=t(data.mat))
         x.labels=data.frame(City=rownames(data.mat))
         y.labels=data.frame(Order=colnames(data.mat))

         imagesend(plot.call=plot.call,
            y.pos=yy,
            x.pos=xx,
            mai.mat=mai.mat, mai.prc=mai.prc,
            xy.type="image.box",
            x.labels=x.labels,
            y.labels=y.labels,
            xy.labels = xy.labels,
            image.size="500x800",
            fname.root="exPlotImage",
            font.size=18)

           return (0)
```

Please let me know if you have a solution for this! 
Thank you

Comment: sorry, bad translation from french the right error message is:
    Error in image(x = xx, y = yy, z = zz, col = heat.colors(30),   axes = FALSE)  : 
  object 'xx' not found

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution:
I only have to assign xx,yy,zz to the global environnement and delete them at the end and it works

```
  Heatmap<-function(data.mat,main.str="heatmap"){

     xx <<- 0:dim(data.mat)[1] 
     yy <<- 0:dim(data.mat)[2] 
     zz <<- log(data.mat+1)
     plot.call = "image( x=xx,y=yy, z=zz,col = heat.colors(30),axes = FALSE);
     axis(1,0.5:(dim(data.mat)[1]-0.5),
     labels=rownames(data.mat),
     las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0,cex.axis =1);
     axis(4,0.5:(dim(data.mat)[2]-0.5),
     labels=colnames(data.mat),
     las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0,cex.axis =.8)"
     mai.mat = matrix(c(1.5,.5,.5,1.5), ncol=4)
     mai.prc = FALSE
     xy.labels=list(nb_of_sequences=t(data.mat))
     x.labels=data.frame(City=rownames(data.mat))
     y.labels=data.frame(Order=colnames(data.mat))

     imagesend(plot.call=plot.call,
        y.pos=yy,
        x.pos=xx,
        mai.mat=mai.mat, mai.prc=mai.prc,
        xy.type="image.box",
        x.labels=x.labels,
        y.labels=y.labels,
        xy.labels = xy.labels,
        image.size="500x800",
        fname.root="exPlotImage",
        font.size=18)

  rm(xx,envir = .GlobalEnv)
  rm(yy,envir = .GlobalEnv)
  rm(zz,envir = .GlobalEnv)
  return (0)
}
```

but I guess it is not the best solution ... let me know if you have a better one